# Git filter-repo does not make changes to my files locally and remotely - is that normal?

Tags: git, github

I followed the steps from the official github link : [Removing sensitive data from a repository](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository)

- I installed git-repo-filter
- I cloned my repo to a fresh directory
- Ran the cmd `git filter-repo --invert-paths --path *filename*`

*I have tried here to both use the filename only, the relative and the absolute path with both backslash and forward slashes (I am running on windows)*

Got a positive result. But at this point, nothing has changed on my local repo - is that normal?
Then I add to set again the remote origin of the repo, because that was gone.
Then I force push the commit to the remote using `git push origin --force --all`

But the result is "Everything up-to-date".

So nothing has changed both locally and remotely.

I must've made a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Did you remember to do the `git rm` at the end?

Comment: I did not see that anywhere....? If so, at what step?

Comment: I guess you're right — the issue must be the actual `filter-repo` command you gave.